# Unable to abort, skip git rebase, due to strange permission problems in windows

Tags: git, rebase, abort

**Env**

- Windows: 7
- Git: 1.9.5.msysgit.1

I ran into strange permission problems while rebasing. I tried to abort but in vain.

```
$ git rebase --abort
rm: cannot unlink `c:/git/my-repo/.git/rebase-merge/.git-rebase-todo.swp': Permission denied
rm: cannot remove directory `c:/git/my-repo/.git/rebase-merge': Directory not empty
```

I tried to skip abort, it too results in similar problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Move those folders to some other location on your computer/

```
.git/rebase-merge
.git/rebase-apply
```

You might not have both but if you do move them both.

---

#### Solution 2:

restart your git-bash, they might be a lock on the file so restart will release it.

Comment: I tried the **solution2**, restarting the whole machine. It seems to have removed the locks.